# How are phones designed on “The Dirty Pair?”

Tags: dirty-pair

The two heroines in TV series *The Dirty Pair* work for the World Welfare Works Association (WWWA / 3WA) as “trouble consultants”, for example solving problems while blowing things up..

During the opening credits—and during the show—characters are seen using the phone to call WWWA with the number “3WA” being dialed on the keypad.

[image: Screenshot of the dialing pad of a phone in “Dirty Pair.”]

This style of keypad shows up throughout the show—and as far as I know—it’s not a standard style keypad outside of the world of “The Dirty Pair.”

Even if the <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> keys were there for the exclusive purpose of dialing “3WA” why are <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> keys there?

Is there an explanation—in universe or otherwise—of why phones keypads are designed this way in the series?

[image: Screenshot of the dialing pad of a phone in “The Dirty Pair.”]

[image: Screenshot of a phone on the wall showing the full dialing pad in “Dirty Pair.”]

Comment: Perhaps for (Y)es (N)o?

Comment: Maybe. They generally just pick up the phone and talk after typing, rather than having a call/clear press