# Is this computer keyboard on “The Dirty Pair” based on a real world keyboard?

Tags: dirty-pair

Somewhat [inspired by this other question the phone keypad design](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/35729/20254), does the keyboard pictured below—as seen in the first TV episode of *The Dirty Pair*, “How to Kill a Computer”—have any real world analog? I don’t recall ever seeing a keyboard that was in a <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> arrangement.

[image: Computer keyboard from “The Dirty Pair.”]